# How to change following date to 2 specific forms? (linux terminal/shell)

Tags: linux, shell, terminal, sh

If I type "date" on linux terminal, it shows

> Wed Apr  5 11:00:29 EDT 2017

My question is is there a way to show it in following 2 forms? using only "date" command or shell script?

17-April-5 wed

- wed is all lower case
- 17-April-5 is year-month-day form

17-4-5 WED

- WED is all upper case
- 17-4-5 is year-month-day form

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish what you want with the date command and tr.  I created a script that takes a parm ($1) and converts it (assuming it's a date) to the formats you want:

```
tmp()
{
  d8out1="$(date -d $1 +%y-%B-%-d) $(date -d $1 +%a | tr [:upper:] [:lower:])"
  echo $d8out1
  d8out2=$(date -d $1 +"%y-%-m-%-d %^a")
  echo $d8out2
}
```

The date formats use the following options:

```
%y  -- Two digit year (use %Y (uppercase) for four digits)
%B  -- Full month name (e.g., April)
%-m -- Month number -- the hyphen ("-") says do not pad the field (4 instead of 04)
%-d -- Day of month -- again, the hyphen suppresses padding
%a  -- abbreviated weekday name (e.g. Wed) -- tr is then used to shift the case.
%^a -- abbreviated weekday name -- the caret ("^") says to upshift it
```

Note that if you didn't care about the case of the day name, the first version could be done in one simple statement, same as the second one (only without the caret to upshift the day, of course).

Here are a couple of sample runs:

```
> tmp 04/05/2017
17-April-5 wed
17-4-5 WED

> tmp 12/31/2017
17-December-31 sun
17-12-31 SUN

> tmp 11/30/1965
65-November-30 tue
65-11-30 TUE
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
$ date +"%g-%B-$(echo `date +%e`) $(date +%a|tr [:upper:] [:lower:])"                                              
17-April-5 wed
$ date +"%g-$(date +%m|sed 's/^0//')-$(echo `date +%e`) $(date +%a|tr [:lower:] [:upper:])"                        
17-4-5 WED
```

Comment: no sed or awk; I am sorry. only date command, shell script, or all linux command except sed, awk.